# How to find individual probabilities of all numbers from a list?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have the following list of random numbers:

```
 lis1={0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 
    9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
    12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
    14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 
    17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 
    19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
    21, 21, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 
    23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 24, 
    24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 24, 25, 
    25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 26, 26, 
    26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 26, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 31, 31, 
    32, 33, 34, 35, 38, 50}
```

What I'd like to do is figure out the probability of picking a number from the list without having to input each number separately.  For example:  If I wanted to find the probability of picking out a 0, I could perform:

```
0.+ Count[lis1,0] / 276
```

I could use this method for each unique number that appears, but that seems rather inconvenient for larger lists.  Is there a simpler way to just iterate through all the unique numbers which appear in the list and find their respective probabilities?  I would like to ultimately put all these probabilities into a list:

```
{Probability of picking 0, probability of picking 1, probability of picking 2, etc.}
```

Comment: `Counts[#] / Length[#]& @ lis1`?

Comment: Same results but output as a list of 2-element lists:  `{#[[1]], #[[2]]/Length[lis1]} & /@ Tally[lis1]`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) + [`PDF`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PDF.html):

```
ed = EmpiricalDistribution[lis1];

pdf = PDF[ed];


pdf /@ {0, 5, 22, 100}
```

> ```
> {1/92, 1/69, 5/92, 0}
> ```

You can use the properties `"Domain"` and `"Weights"` to get the *unique numbers* in `lis1` and the list of probabilities:

```
ed["Domain"]
```

> ```
>  {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
>  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
>  38, 50}
> ```

```
ed["Weights"]
```

> ```
> {1/92, 5/276, 3/92, 5/276, 5/276, 1/69, 5/276, 7/276, 1/92, 5/138, 
>  1/69, 1/46, 2/69, 3/92, 2/69, 3/92, 11/276, 5/138, 3/92, 17/276, 
>  11/276, 1/23, 5/92, 4/69, 17/276, 7/138, 1/23, 5/138, 7/276, 5/276, 
>  1/138, 1/138, 1/276, 1/276, 1/276, 1/276, 1/276, 1/276}
> ```

```
Grid[{Prepend["x"] @ ed["Domain"], Prepend["prob(x)"] @ ed["Weights"]}, 
   Dividers -> All]
```

[image]